# How to optimise nested for-loop operation on a row of pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have a pandas DataFrame of 10,000 rows. Each of these rows contain a 1D np.array. I want to compute Euclidean distance (and a few other measurements) on each of these arrays (rows) with respect to every other array (row). I can do this in 3 ways, but all these approaches require high computing time. Is there an optimised way to achieve this? I'm sharing a brief code of what I did-

`df` is the DataFrame and `vector` is the column name. The df looks like this-

```
#Method-1:

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[0]):
        get_distance(df['vector'][i], df['vector'][j])
```

```
#Method-2:

def func(n, df):
    return df.apply(lambda x: get_distance(n,x))

df.vector.apply(lambda x: func(x,df.vector))
```

```
#Method-3:

features = list(product(df.vector.values, df.vector.values))

data = [get_distance(i[0], i[1]) for i in features]
```

Is there an optimised way to achieve this?

Thank you!

P.S. I'm not concerned about the output data type. The output can be a list (like in Methods 1 and 3), a DataFrame (like in Method 2), an array, a matrix, etc. I'm only trying to improve the effeciently.

Comment: Well, for one, isn't the euclidean distance commutative? If it is, ensure the vectors are in monotonic order (`get_distance(*sorted(va, vb))`) and slap an `@lru_cache()` decorator on the distance function, and you should get a whole lot less computation.

Comment: @AKX Thank you for the suggestion. It never occurred to me to use caching. I implemented it and it did reduce the computation time. However, out of curiosity, I'm wondering if there is any method/function in pandas to replace the nested loop that can fasten the iteration.